# Is there any way to perform this animation with just one click if you want to repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/hugoC12/pen/gOrQyya)

```
var btt = document.querySelector('.btt');
  btt.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle('anime');
});
```

How can I achieve this effect by clicking only once?

Comment: you want the color to be changed continuously by one click?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please copy your codepen to a `[<>]` stack snippet here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand what you mean.

To repeat the same animation with a single click, the following style within the mudaCor class would suffice.

```
  animation-iteration-count:infinite/*or a numbre*/;
```

The css file would be the following

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

@keyframes mudaCor{
  0%{
    background:orange;
  }
  50%{
    background:blue;
  }
  100%{
    background:orange;
  }
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

.btt{
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  background:orange;
}


.mudaCor{
  animation:mudaCor 2s linear;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite/*or a numbre*/;
}
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to create this kind of behavior. What you'll want to do is when clicking the button remove the class and re-add the class back to restart the animation.

```js
var btt = document.querySelector('.btt');
btt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.remove('mudaCor');
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.classList.add('mudaCor');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes mudaCor {
  0% {
    background: orange;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background: orange;
  }
}

.btt {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

.mudaCor {
  animation: mudaCor 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button class="btt">CLIQUE1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `setInterval` to run the click code in loop.

```js
var btt = document.querySelectorAll('.btt')[0];
btt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let elem = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    elem.classList.toggle('mudaCor')
  }, 1500)
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes mudaCor {
  0% {
    background: orange;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background: orange;
  }
}

.btt {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

.mudaCor {
  animation: mudaCor 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btt">CLIQUE1</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add the `infinite` value to the `animation` property?